# Cheat Engine vs Ollydbg

Tags: debugging, memory, ram, ollydbg, cheat-engine

What is the difference between both programs besides that one is used for cheating at games and the other is a debugger? I know that Cheat Engine is a memory editor. But what does Ollydbg do exactly; does it only edit .exe files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CE it's focused on memory editing and analisys, Olly can do the same as CE but its focus is code analysis and patching, there is tasks that you can use both, a case is that CE can easily find a portion of code that changes memory (Olly can do it too but CE makes it very easy) and than you can modify the code with olly.

Answer (score 1):

OllyDbg is a 32-bit assembler level analyzing debugger with a lot of  tools Emphasizing on binary code analysis makes it particularly useful in cases 
where source is unavailable.
but cheat engine is simple and user friendly app designed
for easier searching in memory and making simple scripts for trainers.

Comment: If you ask me which to choose I prefer OllyDBG